# Resize menu with icons without breaking

Tags: html, css

I have an icon menu on the top of a page I'm developing using Avada Wordpress theme. I am trying to make it so when the page is resized the icons and menu headers keep shrinking, and the words of the menu break.

I already disabled the mobile menu breakpoint (I think) and now would just like to get this done).

At full screen I have this:
[image]

At mobile resolutions I have this:

[image]

What I would like is for the the text to break at the spaces. So "Smart Home" becomes "Smart + newline + Home" and for all the menu items to remain on one line. If the width of the viewer keeps decreasing then just keep decreasing the font and icon size, but never break between the menu items.

I did try to implement a calc function for the css but I am new to that.

Website is here: www.paradigmtek.com (under construction)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a fixed width for the `li` elements in the menu, here's the code changes that you need for your specific page:

```
.fusion-main-menu > ul > li {
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.fusion-main-menu li {
   width: calc(16% - 10px);
}
```

The only thing left would be to change the font size, you can either choose a relative unit of measurement (eg. `vw`, `%`, `em` etc.), or what I'd advice is to use media queries and manually test all the resolutions to ensure the menu is both readable and looks good on all screen sizes - you shouldn't go below `12px` or so (the exact value is debatable)

Answer (score 0):

add this with media query for the size you want to change the text and add another media query to have max-width of the menu item

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 540px) {
     body.fusion-top-header.avada-sticky-shrinkage .fusion-header-wrapper:not(.fusion-is-sticky) .fusion-main-menu>ul>li>a.fusion-flex-link {
          max-width: 80px;
          line-height: 1!important;
}
.menu-text{
          word-break: break-word;
 }
}
```